# Probability density function with triangular distribution of parameters

Tags: r, probability

How do you compute this probability density function, with a triangular distribution of parameters (a,b,c)?

```
f(x)= 0 , x<a
      2(x-a)/((b-a)(c-a)) , a <= x <= c
      2(b-x)/((b-a)(b-c)) , c < x <=b
      0 , x> b
```

Comment: Do you know `if ... else if ...` ?

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate it at a point x?

Comment: yeah @GoldenGateBridge

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yeah but I didn't know you can make a probability density function with if, else if, if you could just give me an example that you be great, I can't find it anywhere

Comment: `f <- function(x) { if(x<a) 0 else if(x>=c) 2*(x-a)/((b-a)*(c-a)) else if(x<=b) ...`. Can you continue?

Comment: To be sure... do you want to *evaluate* f(x) for a given x? Or something else?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent better to use nested `ifelse()` (vectorized) rather than `if` / `else` (not vectorized) here, no?

Comment: @zephryl Totally agreed. But to explain the principle to a novice, I think that using `if`/`else`at first is more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @StéphaneLaurent‘s comments, you can define a piecewise function using a series of `ifelse()` calls (or `dplyr::case_when()`).

```
f <- function(x, A, B, C) {
  out <- ifelse(
    x < A | B < x,
    0,
    ifelse(
      A <= x & x <= C,
      (2*(x-A))/((B-A)*(C-A)),
      ifelse(
        C < x & x <= B,
        (2*(B-x))/((B-A)*(B-C)),
        NA_real_
  )))
  if (any((is.na(out) | is.nan(out)) & (!is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)))) {
    warning("f(x) undefined for some input values")
  }
  out
}
```

Taking it for a spin:

```
library(ggplot2) 
dat <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(-1.5, 1.5, by = 0.1),
  A = -1:1,
  B = -1:1,
  C = -1:1
)

dat$y <- with(dat, f(x, A, B, C))
# Warning message:
# In f(x, A, B, C) : f(x) undefined for some input values

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(C))) +
  facet_grid(B ~ A, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove some conditions. For example `A <= x` in the second condition is necessarily fulfilled if the first condition is not fulfilled. And the last `ifelse` is useless, for similar reasons its condition is always fulfilled if the preceding ones are not.

Comment: Just seen your example. Not very nice since one should assume `A < B < C`. My previous comment applies in this case only.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, and in addition the function yields `NaN` due to division by 0 for some inputs. But my goal was to show OP how to implement their function as given, not to also critique or revise their function, which is a separate question. The reason I built in a warning is to highlight these potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option for a density function and a random function.

```
dtri <- function(x, A, B, C) {
  n <- length(x)
  i <- 1:n
  if (length(A) == 1) A <- rep(A, n)
  if (length(B) == 1) B <- rep(B, n)
  if (length(C) == 1) C <- rep(C, n)
  abc <- Rfast::rowSort(matrix(c(A, B, C), n, 3))
  bln <- x < abc[,2]
  p <- 2*abs(x - abc[i + 2*n*!bln])/(abc[,3] - abc[,1])/(abc[i + n*(2 - bln)] - abc[i + n*(1 - bln)])
  p[x < abc[,1] | x > abc[,3]] <- 0
  p
}

rtri <- function(n, a, b, c) {
  if (a > b) {a <- (b - a) + (b <- a)}
  if (b > c) {c <- (b - c) + (b <- c)}
  fb <- (b - a)/(c - a)
  U <- runif(n)
  blna <- U < fb
  r <-numeric(n)
  r[blna] <- a + sqrt(U[blna]*(c - a)*(b - a))
  r[!blna] <- c - sqrt((1 - U[!blna])*(c - a)*(c - b))
  r
}
```

Comment: Some parts of this look funny. (1) This isn't vectorized, but user could pass vectors of length > 1, in which case the first line of the body (`if (x < a | x >c)`) will be weird (may return a warning or error, I haven't checked); (2) lines 2-3 of body ; `a <- (b - a) +  (b <- a)` does **something** (since assignments return a value), but seem very strange.

Comment: Right. I think I fixed the density function to be fully vectorized. It still doesn't guard against a == b or b == c.

Answer (score 0):

Using R's vectorized cabilities:

```
my_fun <- function(x, a, b, c) {

  i1 <- x >= a & x <= c
  i2 <- x >  c & x <= b
  
  f <- rep(NA, length(x))
  f[x < a | x > b] <- 0
  f[i1] <- 2 * (x[i1] - a) / ((b - a) * (c - a))
  f[i2] <- 2 * (b - x[i2]) / ((b - a) * (b - c))
  return(f)
}
```

Test:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sort(rnorm(1000, 0, 5))
a <- runif(1, -10, -2)
c <- runif(1, -2, 2)
b <- runif(1, 2, 10)

f <- my_fun(x, a, b, c)
plot(x, f, type="l")
```

[image]